# Laravel validations

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate my backend code with the following data.I passed date as `$request->get('date_from')`,`$request->get('date_to')` and time as `$request->get('time_from')`, `$request->get('time_to')` from my angular frontend and I convert date time as follows.

```
$dateTime_from=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->get('date_from'))).' '.$request->get('time_from');
$dateTime_to=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->get('date_to'))).' '.$request->get('time_to');
```

Now I want to validate DateTime with laravel backend validations. `dateTime_from` should be less than `dateTime_to`.How can write down that code inside validator?

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'vehicle_id'=>'required',
            'time_to'=>'required',
            'event_id'=>'required',

        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after` validation rule.

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'vehicle_id' => 'required',
  'date_to'    => 'required|after:date_from',
  'event_id'   => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: I want to compare $dateTime_from with $dateTime_to is there any way to do that?

Comment: @GayalSeneviratne Isn't that what he has posted?

Comment: @Cerlin not only date_from should be less than $date_to. For instance, let's say if frontend passed same $date_from and $date_to. I want to clarify with the time too. for example $dateTime_from=2019-1-5 08:30:00 $dateTime_to=2019-1-5 07:00:00 then this instance $dateTime_from greater tha the $dateTime_to. this is the issue I want to handle

Comment: Laravel uses php's `strtotime` method. So time will also be considered while validating. So please try the solution mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-after

you can use the after rule like follows

```
'date_to' => 'required|date|after:date_from'
```

Instead of passing a date string to be evaluated by `strtotime`, you may specify another field to compare against the date:

Also, you have [rule-before](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-before) as well

**EDIT**
I think `after` rule takes the time into consideration as well, but not sure.

And you have really complex validation to do, better write a [custom rule class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules) or a closure to handle it for you

```
'date_to' => [ 'required', 
               'date',
               function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                  if (strtotime($value) <= strtotime($request->date_from) {
                  $fail(':attribute needs to be higher than date_from!'); // or whatever mesage ou need to send
               }
             ]
```

Comment: not only date_from should be less than $date_to. For instance, let's say if frontend passed same $date_from and $date_to. I want to clarify with the time too. for example $dateTime_from=2019-1-5 08:30:00 $dateTime_to=2019-1-5 07:00:00 then this instance $dateTime_from greater tha the $dateTime_to. this is the issue I want to handle

Comment: Edited answer, please check